# Unknown column al usar WHERE(ERROR) codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de mostrar un valor de la Base de datos en un input, sin embargo me arroja el siguiente error. ¿Por que sucede esto?

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '17811942-4' in 'where clause'

SELECT `horario`.`hrs_ini` FROM `horario` JOIN `usuarios` ON `horario`.`rut_usu` = `usuarios`.`rut_usu` WHERE `usuarios`.`rut_usu` = `17811942-4` AND `horario`.`lunes` = `ATTE`. `ESTUDIANTES`

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/SAE/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Consulta en la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo

```
public function lunes(){


$this->db->select('horario.hrs_ini');
$this->db->from('horario');
$this->db->join('usuarios','horario.rut_usu = usuarios.rut_usu');
$this->db->where('usuarios.rut_usu=17811942-4');
$this->db->where('horario.lunes=ATTE. ESTUDIANTES');
$start_lunes = $this->db->get();


if($start_lunes->num_rows() > 0 ){

    return $start_lunes->result();

    }

}
```

Controlador

```
public function index(){


        $this->load->view('layouts/header.php');
        $this->load->view('layouts/menu.php');


        $this->load->model('mCalendar');
        $data['start_lunes'] = $this->mCalendar->lunes();
        $data['usuarios'] = $this->mCalendar->get_usuarios();
        $data2['motivos'] = $this->mCalendar->get_motivos();
        $this->load->view('usuarios/vConsulta_Horarios.php',$data,$data2);
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer.php');




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas conparando mal los valores en el where, deberia ser de esta manera:

```
$this->db->where('usuarios.rut_usu','XXXXXXXX-X'); $this->db->where('horario.lunes','ATTE. ESTUDIANTES');
```

Comment: Justamente estimado, ese era el error, pero al pasar la variable value="<?php echo $start_lunes;?>" me dice Message: Array to string conversion¿ como deberia de pasarlo entonces?

Comment: Estas devolviendo el resultado de tu consulta en forma de arreglo, result (),  el cual se utiliza cuando tu consulta devuelbe mas de una fila y necesitas recorrer con un foreach, en tu caso solo devuelbes un resultado deberias utilizar, start_lunes->row ();

Answer (score 1):

El error está en esta linea:

```
$this->db->where('usuarios.rut_usu=17811942-4');
```

Está intentando buscar donde el valor de la columna 'usuarios.rut_usu' es igual al valor de la columna '17811942-4'.
Lo correcto sería:

```
$this->db->where('usuarios.rut_usu','17811942-4');
```

Esto busca donde el valor de la columna 'usuarios.rut_usu' es igual a '17811942-4'

Mira esta docu:
https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Comment: por favor cambia los valores de consulta es informacion delicada del usuario

Comment: Gracias por  responder

Comment: JackNavaRow  el 'usuarios.rut_usu','17811942-4' es ficticio XD